# Collecting an Oyster card refund without tapping in

Tags: london, refunds, tfl, oyster-card

I've had a service delay refund approved for my Oyster card today, but I only have 2 days to tap in to collect it. Its a Friday and I'm not travelling for a few days, is there a way I can collect it without tapping in? The email specifies you can't collect it from a ticket machine...

Comment: The TFL site says you have 28 days from the delay. So presumably your journey happened 26 days ago?

Comment: @mattfreake I believe one has 28 days form the delay to _put forward a claim_, and once the refund approved there is a very short window (2 or 3 days, probably max 7) where you can _collect_ the refund. The OP seems to be in the latter stage. Having that said, I believe (but am unable to locate any sources) that the collection period is usually longer than that advertised, but the OP can probably advise what has happened by now.